# Integration of always positive input is negative in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, sampling, numerical-integration

In MATLAB/Simulink I have calculated integration of a signal which is always positive:

However, the integration result of this signal is **negative**!!!

How is it possible?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx0RX.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC3tK.jpg]

Comment: Please post an image with your signal generator as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible. Your function could be taking negative values as well but the graphic scale doesn't shows off those values because is also outputting high positive values, check your input function near to zero (scale up)

## UPDATE

Choose the most appropiate solver for your signal. This link can be useful

> http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/choosing-a-solver.html

Comment: The input signal is square of some other signals which cannot be negative. I have scaled up and it still shows positive. I even added a saturation to cut negative inputs. It does not help. Even ABS block on input signal does not help. I am afraid it is because of a MATLAB bug or sampling time or because of sudden changes of input.

Comment: Did you fixed your lower saturation limit to zero? When the integral is less than or equal to the Lower saturation limit, the output is held at the Lower saturation limit.

Comment: Mathematically is not possible to get a negative integration value in a function with positive outcomes

Comment: Yes it is: http://s16.postimg.org/ov77vk2np/zz_Capture4.png , interestingly when i save signals into workspace and load them from workspace in another simulink or even in original simulink model they work fine but it does not work when signal is generated directly!

Comment: lol But just in your case. It looks like a simulink problem. Did you fixed your lower saturation limit to zero?

Comment: definitely is a MATLAB issue. Check  your integration method, must be ODE5